# Join two split files

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have lots of files eg.

a.xxx.001
a.xxx.002

b.yyy.001
b.yyy.002
b.yyy.003

How can I merge then into: a.xxx and b.yyy? In Ubuntu

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the original file was straightforwardly split into chunks (so the chunks don't have headers or anything like that), use the con**cat**enate command:

```
cat a.xxx.??? >a.xxx
```

Make sure that you have all the pieces, since `cat` will just concatenate what it's given. If your shell is bash (the default shell) or zsh, you can use

```
cat a.xxx.{001..002} >a.xxx
cat b.yyy.{001..003} >b.yyy
```

This way, `cat` is given the names of the *expected* pieces in order, so you will get an error message if any of the pieces is missing.

Comment: Assuming that the current working directory contains only those pieces, he can also use `cat a.xxx.* > cat a.xxx`.

Comment: @Cristian: I didn't use `*` because it's more failure-prone. If the pieces are called …, `a.xxx.9`, `a.xxx.10`, …, it's obvious that `.???` won't work, whereas `.*` would silently concatenate the pieces in the wrong order. `.???` is also a little more robust against stray files being caught, though `.[0-9][0-9][0-9]` would be safer (but would require significantly more typing).

Comment: @Giles: a good split program would use proper file names for the pieces to avoid this issue.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat a.xxx.001 a.xxx.002 > a.xxx
$ cat b.yyy.001 b.yyy.002 b.yyy.003 > b.xxx
```

Comment: Your idea is good, but he said that he has *lots of files*, not only a couple of files.

Comment: Not sure how the previous comment relates; both answers do it well, but you should definitely be using wild cards instead of explicitly listing them.

Comment: True. The answer below is better. Btw, to do it on modification date, something like "cat `ls -tr a.xxx.*` > a.xxx" would work.

Comment: @Redmumba: yeah, I was referring to wildcards.